# Repair One Drive Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I am having problems with one drive on windows 10. I tried to uninstall and hope to reinstall it. It seems to be in a weird state where it is not installed but not uninstalled.

I can't install it as it says I got to remove the old version. When I click uninstall nothing happens.

I deleted one drive from the registry but sill did not help.

Comment: Have you tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c and https://lifehacker.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-onedrive-in-windows-10-1725363532 and then reinstalling it?